# Get cursor back after killing xkill

Tags: linux, ubuntu, fedora, x11, kill

Assume that you accidentally typed `xkill` on a terminal and you killed by `Ctrl+Z` or `Ctrl+X`.
Now the cursor is an `X` and it doesn't really function.

How can I get the cursor back without rebooting the PC?

Comment: Did you try restarting the x session, possibly by executine gnome-session or by systemctl isolate graphical.target?

Comment: This looks like a bug with your distro or Unix. On Fedora 32 I cannot reproduce it.

Comment: @Dani_l I tried to restart `cinnamon` but the PC crashed so I did a brute-force restart

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Oh that's good actually! I think though that I had the same issue on `f32` a few months ago.

Comment: *killed by `Ctrl+Z`*?  That's not killed - that's almost certainly *suspended*.  The `xkill` process still exists, but it's been stopped and relegated to the background. Your cursor can't do anything because X click events are still being sent  to `xkill`, but it's **stopped** and not doing anything. `ps -f` should show the `xkill` process, and you can `kill PID`.  Or `fg` then `ctrl-C`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle That looks like an answer. Would you like to post it?

Comment: @AndrewHenle : Damn... You are perfectly right...

Answer (score 1):

I guess @Andrew Henle mentioned a solution but didn't post it as an answer.

Posting it as an answer for someone stuck at it.

> *killed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>*? That's not killed — that's almost certainly *suspended*. The `xkill` process still exists, but it's been stopped and relegated to the background. Your cursor can't do anything because X click events are still being sent to `xkill`, but it's **stopped** and not doing anything. `ps -f` should show the `xkill` process, and you can `kill PID`. Or `fg` then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

That's his whole [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/612605/get-cursor-back-after-killing-xkill/706558#comment1143869_612605).

Comment: If you *are* going to copy and quote something, at least accurately reproduce and format it correctly. Also, use blockquote formatting, rather than code formatting.